# insert multiple data mysql using for loop

Tags: mysql, vb.net, winforms

This is the scenario, I have a select query then all fetched data must be inserted into another table.. This is what I came up, I don't know if the for loop does anything.

If I would remove the for loop.
Example:
Fetched data is id1, id2, id3
the inserted data in my database is id1, id1, id1 instead of id1, id2, id3

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM dummy_violate WHERE res_month <> @month Or res_year <> @year"
    cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, con)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@month", DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM"))
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy"))
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    While dr.Read
        id += dr(0)
        count += 1
    End While
    dr.Close()
    If count > 0 Then

        For i As Integer = 1 To count
            sql2 = "INSERT INTO dummy_violate(res_id, res_month, res_year, is_paid)VALUES(@id,@month,@year,@paid)"
            cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql2, con)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@month", DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM"))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy"))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paid", 0)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
    ElseIf count = 0 Then

        MsgBox("Wrong Query")

    End If
```

Comment: I needed to rename the title and some other things in my problem, sorry bout that.

Comment: 'another table' ? It look same table.

Comment: What's your point? my problem is not the table.. problem is insert multiple data

Comment: If the ID is the primary key of your table then you cannot insert multiple record with the same ID. Is the ID your primary key for the table `dummy_violate`?

Comment: nope my dummy_violate does not contain a primary key..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand what you are trying to do and why, it seems that you are simply duplicating the records already present in your table with new records with the same data but with the is_paid flag set to zero. If so just try changing your code in this way:

```
sql = "SELECT res_id FROM dummy_violate WHERE res_month <> @month Or res_year <> @year"
cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, con)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@month", DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM"))
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy"))
Dim da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
Dim dt = new DataTable()
da.Fill(dt)

' if we have records to duplicate we have Rows.Count > 0
If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
   sql2 = "INSERT INTO dummy_violate(res_id, res_month, res_year, is_paid) " & _ 
          "VALUES(@id,@month,@year,@paid)"
    cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql2, con)

    ' Add all the parameters before entering the loop. Just @id changes for every loop,
    ' so we set it with a dummy value outside the loop and we change it when looping over
    ' the result table.....
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 0) 
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@month", DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM"))
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy"))
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paid", 0)

    ' execute the insert for all the rows count 
    ' rows array starts at zero so loop to count -1
    For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
        cmd.Parameters("@id").Value = dt.Rows(i)("res_id")
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Next
ElseIf count = 0 Then
    MsgBox("Wrong Query")
End If
```

Remember that if the res_id is a primary key then you cannot insert the records with the same res_id twice. Also, if res_id is an auto_number column (a.k.a. IDENTITY) then you cannot explicitily set its value

Comment: Thank you.. Code Works.. but how can it be done that If data exist It would not insert anymore..

Comment: That's a lot more complex. If you set a primary key with res_id, res_month and res_year, the insert will fail and you need to trap the exception. Instead if you want to check before the insert you need another query that check the presence of the three values to avoid duplication. This second approach is probably the best but more complex. Please try to add a new question so other people could see it and help